# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when executing CLR Stored Procedure to run a Cognos Report

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, sdk, cognos, clrstoredprocedure

Good Morning.  I am currently experiencing an issue with a CLR Stored procedure calling an assembly created in Visual Basic (VS 2008).  At the highest level, the assembly executes a report contained in Cognos8 and moves the output to a specificed directory on the network.  I have no issue when calling the method from a simple test EXE, but when I try to execute via the CLR stored procedure, I am getting the following:

Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ReportRunner, Line 0

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ReportRunner":

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'cognosdotnetassembly_2_0, Version=10.1.4707.501, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d6e6d7d808b7e5b7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)

at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)

at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)

at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(String partialName, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(String partialName, Evidence securityEvidence)

at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(Type type, String defaultNamespace, XmlSerializerImplementation& contract)

at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
    at cognosdotnet_2_0.reportService1..ctor()

at ReportRunnerv3.ReportRunner.ExecuteReport(Int32 inPLAN_ID, Int32 inContract_Sfx, String inRptDate_DT, String inPlanType, String inInvstmentOnlyInd, String inMOMInd, String inGPSIInd, String inPBTInd, String inPICAInd, String inClientAccomInd, String inInstSelectInd, String inRptType, Int32& outRC)

Notes
 •cognosdotnetassembly_2_0 is located in the same directory as the "ReportRunner" assembly
 •cognosdotnetassembly_2_0 was cataloged using CREATE ASSEMBLY with permission set = unsafe
 •cognosdotnetassembly_2_0 is also installed in the GAC

The following is the message provided by fuslogvw.exe:

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/11/2011 @ 5:57:39 AM) ***

The operation failed.

Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll

Running under executable  c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe

--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

LOG: DisplayName = cognosdotnetassembly_2_0, Version=10.1.4707.501, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d6e6d7d808b7e5b7
  (Fully-specified)

LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS/MSSQL/Binn/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL

LOG: Cache Base = NULL

LOG: AppName = NULL

Calling assembly : System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

===

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
 LOG: No application configuration file found.

LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.

LOG: Post-policy reference: cognosdotnetassembly_2_0, Version=10.1.4707.501, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d6e6d7d808b7e5b7

LOG: Fusion is hosted. Check host about this assembly.

LOG: Assembly is not in CLR Loaded list. Asking host assembly store.

LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly cognosdotnetassembly_2_0, version=10.1.4707.501, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=d6e6d7d808b7e5b7, processorarchitecture=x86.

LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly cognosdotnetassembly_2_0, version=10.1.4707.501, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=d6e6d7d808b7e5b7, processorarchitecture=msil.

LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly cognosdotnetassembly_2_0, version=10.1.4707.501, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=d6e6d7d808b7e5b7.

WRN: Host assembly store does not contain this assembly.

ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).

Can someone provide insight as to why SQL Server is unable to find cognosdotnetassembly_2_0?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks for your assistance.

--Chris

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago but in the hopes that it will help someone in the future I'm including what I know.

This is probably related to the Security restrictions that are built into the SQL CLR system. I had issues while trying to use XML Serialization inside of a CLR SQL Sproc, because (and your error log shows this as well) XML Serialization actually uses Reflection which requires more security permissions than normal managed code. I'm guessing you were able to reference the Cognos assembly because it was added via Browsing for the file. If you add a GAC'ed Assembly the list is very limited I'm sure it's based on a specific interface or assembly attribute, which isn't implemented or available in the Cognos Assembly you are using.

If your CLR SQL sproc runs with a higher permission level it might work. Most likely not.